# in contingency tables with significant association, how to measure the degree of association?

Tags: r, contingency-tables

with contingency tables (RxC, not square) measuring the force of association with the cramer´v test. I know that the strength of association is moderate, but I want to know the grade of that association, for example, the grade of strength of association is 30%.

What test should I use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your two variables have order. Then you can select Gamma, Kendall’s Tau-b, Stuart’s Tau-c, Somers’ D, Pearson correlation coefficient by using the scores, Spearman Rank Correlation Coefficient, etc.. You can find them from internet and make the choice. For each statistics, there is corresponding statistical test.

Comment: for example, I calculate the tau c of kendall (0.0722), I know that the sign tells me the direction of the relationship; The number that this test generates can I interpret as the grade of the association (7% is the strength of association)?

Comment: The numerator of tau c is (# of concordant pair - # of discordant pair). So 0.0722 means your # of concordant pair is little more than # of discordant pair, and you can say the association between two variables is very weak even existing. My suggestion is try Spearman Rank Correlation Coefficient.

Comment: I just tried the Spearman Rank Correlation Coefficient. in R, but it tells me that varaibles must be numeric, some command that you can suggest me to perform this test?

Comment: Sorry, I am very familiar with SAS. I believe my R skill is worse than yours.

Comment: I will look for the way to do it in R ajajaaja, so the Spearman Rank Correlation Coefficient tells me the degree of the strength of association ?, That value is what is identified as the rho. ?

Comment: Yes, also called Spearman's rho

Comment: Here is the method to convert char to number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273085/how-to-convert-a-character-vector-to-numeric

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your advice has been very useful for my work. Thank you again.

Comment: The question asks about interpreting Cramer's V, which is appropriate for contingency tables of counts for *nominal* variables.  Why does this answer switch to methods appropriate for *ordinal* variables?